# Sketching Frobenius norm of a tensor with a rank-1 random tensor

Tags: pr.probability, tensor-products, measure-concentration, multilinear-algebra, tensor

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n^k}$ be a $k$-dimensional tensor with $n$ elements along each dimension. Moreover suppose $u_1,u_2,\dots,u_k\sim\text{Unif}(\pm1)^n$ are $n$ dimensional vectors with each of their components drawn iid from Rademacher distribution, and let $U:=u_1\otimes u_2 \otimes \dots \otimes u_k$ be a rank-1 random tensor constructed from these vectors. Finally, let $X:=\langle A, U \rangle$, in which by $\langle, \rangle$ we simply mean the inner product of tensor if we flatten them as vectors.

**Question:**: What is the concentration of $X^2$ around its mean?  As it is shown at the bottom of the post, $\mathbb{E} X^2=\lVert A\rVert_F^2$, i.e., the sum of the square of all elements in the tensor. How can the tails of the distribution around the mean be bounded: $P\left(|X^2-\mathbb{E} X^2|\ge x \right)$? Alternatively, as is typical in many concentration bounds, can the probability be bounded as an $\epsilon$-deviation from the mean: $P\left(|X^2-\mathbb{E} X^2|\ge \epsilon \left(\mathbb{E} X^2\right) \right)$?

**Follow-up** as @IosifPinelis has pointed out in their answer, moments of $X$, $\mathbb{E} X^{2p}$, can be effectively bounded, leading to a tail bound roughly of type $P(X\ge x)\le \exp(-x^{2/k})$. However, the main question was to bound the tail bounds of $X^2$ around its mean, which is $P(|X^2-\mathbb{E} X^2| \ge x)$. Taking a similar approach as @IosifPinelis, one could try to bound the tails of $Y:=X^2 - \lVert A\rVert_F^2$ by bounding its moments $\mathbb{E} Y^p$. Is that a sound approach?

**Context:** given that tails are light, this can be seen as sketching the Frobenius norm of a tensor. More so to the point, if $A,B$ are tensors, if we compute $v=\langle A,u_1\otimes \dots\otimes u_k\rangle$ and $w=\langle B,u_1\otimes \dots\otimes u_k\rangle$, then $\mathbb{E}(v-w)^2 = \lVert A-B\rVert_F^2$ and if the concentration is high, it can be seen as a distance-preserving embedding of tensors into the $L^2$-norm. The reason for choosing a rank-1 random tensor as opposed to a fully random one, which makes the bound trivial to compute, is that for certain applications the product with a rank-1 tensor can be computed much more efficiently and hence the sketching is faster to compute.

**Derivation of $\mathbb{E} X^2$:** 
\begin{align*}
 \mathbb{E} X^2 &= \mathbb{E}\sum_{i_1,j_1, \dots,i_k,j_k} a_{i_1, \dots,i_k} a_{j_1,\dots,j_k} u_{1,i_1}\dots u_{k,i_k} u_{1,j_1}\dots u_{k,j_k}\\
&= \sum_{i_1,j_1, \dots,i_k,j_k\le n} a_{i_1, \dots,i_k} a_{j_1,\dots,j_k} \Pi_{m=1}^k \mathbb{E}(u_{m,i_m} u_{m,j_m}) &&\rhd \text{L.o.E, and $u_i$s independence}\\
&= \sum_{i_1,\dots,i_k\le n} a_{i_1,\dots,i_k}^2 && \rhd i_m\neq j_m: \mathbb{E} u_{i_m}u_{j_m} = 0\\
&= \sum_{i_1,\dots,i_k\le n} a_{i_1,\dots,i_k}^2=\lVert A \rVert_F^2 && \rhd \mathbb{E} u_{i_m}^2 = \mathrm{Var}(u_{i_m}) = 1
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tail probability $P(X\ge x)$ is in general like $e^{-x^{2/k}}$ for large $x>0$.

Indeed, we have 
\begin{equation*}
 X=\sum_{i_1,\dots,i_k\le n} a_{i_1,\dots,i_k}u_{1,i_1}\dots u_{k,i_k},  
\end{equation*}
where the $u_{i,j}$'s are assumed to be independent Rademacher random variables. 
Without loss of generality, $|a_{i_1,\dots,i_k}|\le1$ for all $i_1,\dots,i_k$ in $[n]:=\{1,\dots,n\}$. So, for any natural $p$ and $Z\sim N(0,1)$, 
\begin{align*}
  EX^{2p}&=E\prod_{j=1}^{2p}\,\sum_{i_{1,j},\dots,i_{k,j}\le n}
 a_{i_{1,j},\dots,i_{k,j}}u_{1,i_{1,j}}\dots u_{k,i_{k,j}} \\ 
 &=\sum_{j\le2p;\ i_{1,j},\dots,i_{k,j}\le n}\, 
 \Big(\prod_{j=1}^{2p}\,a_{i_{1,j},\dots,i_{k,j}}\Big)\, 
 E\prod_{j=1}^{2p}(u_{1,i_{1,j}}\dots u_{k,i_{k,j}}) \\ 
 &\le\sum_{j\le2p;\ i_{1,j},\dots,i_{k,j}\le n}\, 
 E\prod_{j=1}^{2p}\,(u_{1,i_{1,j}}\dots u_{k,i_{k,j}}) \\ 
 &=E\Big(\sum_{i_1,\dots,i_k\le n} u_{1,i_1}\dots u_{k,i_k}\Big)^{2p} \\  
 &=E\Big(\sum_{i_1\le n} u_{1,i_1}\cdots \sum_{i_k\le n} u_{k,i_k}\Big)^{2p} \\  
 &=E\Big(\sum_{i_1\le n} u_{1,i_1}\Big)^{2p}\cdots E\Big(\sum_{i_k\le n} u_{k,i_k}\Big)^{2p} \\  
 &=\Big(E\Big(\sum_{i\le n} u_{1,i}\Big)^{2p}\Big)^k  \\  
 &\le\Big(E(Z\sqrt n)^{2p}\Big)^k  \\  
 &\le (np)^{kp}.  
\end{align*}
The first inequality in the above multiline display follows because $|a_{i_1,\dots,i_k}|\le1$ and $E\prod_{j=1}^{2p}(u_{1,i_{1,j}}\dots u_{k,i_{k,j}})$ is either $0$ or $1$ and hence $\ge0$; the penultimate inequality there holds by the [Whittle--Haagerup inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eaton%27s_inequality); and the last inequality follows because $EZ^{2p}=(2p-1)!!\le p^p$, as easy to check by induction.

So, by Markov's inequality, for $x>0$ 
\begin{equation*}
 P(X\ge x)\le R(p):=EX^{2p}/x^{2p}\le e^{g(p)},
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
 g(p):=g_x(p):=-p\ln(x^2)+kp\ln(np). 
\end{equation*}
The minimizer of $g(p)$ in all real $p>0$ is $p_x:=x^{2/k}/(en)$, and $R(p_x)=\exp\{-kx^{2/k}/(en)\}$. However, $p_x$ does not have to be an integer. Rounding it to the closest integer and using the facts that $g'(p_x)=0$ and $g''(p)=k/p\to0$ for $p\in[p_x-1/2,p_x+1/2]$ and $x\to\infty$, we conclude that 
\begin{equation*}
 P(X\ge x)\le \exp\{-kx^{2/k}/(en)\}(1+o(1))
\end{equation*}
as $x\to\infty$, as claimed. 
Also, looking back at the above proof, it is easy to see that the obtained upper bound on $P(X\ge x)$ cannot be substantially improved in general.

Comment: Is there a way bound $\mathbb{E}(|X|^p)$ for general $p$ (not limited to integers)? In particular, I'm curious if the result on Khintchine inequality with both $L^1$ and $L^2$-norms terms, can be generalized to the tensor case? (talking about this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khintchine_inequality#Generalizations)

Comment: I can show that, again in the Rademacher case, $$E|X|^q\le(nq)^{kq}\exp\Big\{\frac k{4\max(1,q-2)}\Big\}$$ for all real $q\ge2$. However, in more ways than one, it is better to post additional questions separately.

Comment: how do you convert this result back a concentration for $X^2$ after centering (subtracting its mean)? The upper side is trivial as $X^2-E(X^2)>=t$ implies $X^2>t$, but what about its lower tail? 
Also, I got a bound of $P(X\ge x)\le exp(-x^2/(8n^L)$ using the Taylor expansion of $exp$ and then Markov, I did it because it doesn't need the rounding, but which one is stronger? This bound or the one you've given here?

Comment: When one has additional questions, I think it's better to ask them in separate posts.

Comment: actually, the first part was in the original question. In the post, I was asking for the tail probabilities around the mean  $P(|X^2 - E(X^2)|\ge t)$. 
But you're right about the second question.

Comment: also, in the line that you use the $a_{i_{1,j},\dots,i_{k,j}}\le 1$, the inequality holds for each term if the expectation product $\prod_{j=1}^{2p}\,
 Eu_{1,i_{1,j}}\dots u_{k,i_{k,j}}$ is positive, which as I understand does not necessarily hold, am I missing something?

Comment: (i) The expectation of the product of powers with integer exponents of independent Rademacher random variables can only be $1$ (if all the exponents are even) or $0$ (otherwise). So, such an expectation cannot be negative. (ii) $\prod_{j=1}^{2p}$ was missing/misplaced in two places; these typos are now corrected. (iii) At this point, I don't have good ideas about bounding the lower tail.

Comment: Also, the best possible Markov bound derived from the moments directly should always be better than the best possible Markov bound derived from the moment generating function -- because the latter is just a particular mixture of the moments.

Comment: Can the value of the $E X^{2k}$ be exactly computed if all the values in $A$ are in $\{0,\pm 1\}$, in terms of the number of non-zero elelements